# Is $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+x} - \frac{2}{x^3+2x^2+2x}$ continuous at $x=0?$

Tags: limits, continuity

> Is $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+x} - \frac{2}{x^3+2x^2+2x}$ continuous at $x=0?$

To determine continuous function, $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0)$

I calculated that the $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 0$

Now, $f(0)$ is actually undefined.

I conclude that $x$ is not continuous. However, I used a software to look at the graph of $f(x)$ and it seems that it is continuous at $x=0$.

[image]

Comment: f(0) is undefined,i.e. o does not belong to the domain of f. A function can  be continuous only at a point in its domain.

Comment: Always go to the definition - continuity requires that $f(0)$ be defined, your initial instinct was right. Graphing software won't always show you discontinuities.

Comment: This is an example of what french mathematicians call "**prolongement par continuité**". the point $x=0$ does not belong to the domain of the function $f$ but it is posible to define $f(0)=0$ without contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been explained in the comments, the proposed function cannot be continuous at the origin because it is not even defined at such value. However, after some algebraic manipulations, we arrive at an expression which has a limit at $x = 0$, which also equals zero. Therefore you can define $f(0) = 0$ in order to make $f$ continuous:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x^{2} + x} - \frac{2}{x^{3} + 2x^{2} + 2x} & = \frac{(x^{2} + 2x + 2) - 2(x + 1)}{x(x + 1)(x^{2} + 2x + 2)}\\\\
& = \frac{x^{2}}{x(x + 1)(x^{2} + 2x + 2)}\\\\
& = \frac{x}{(x + 1)(x^{2} + 2x + 2)}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this contributes!

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: So, this contradicts what have been said in the comments. Does this mean $f(x)$ can be continuous and not continuous at the same time?

Comment: The proposed function is not continuous because it is not even defined at zero, but it can be made continuous (over the real line) after removing the removable singularity. Indeed, you can keep the proposed expression for $x\neq 0$ and set $f(0) := 0$.

Comment: Nothing makes a funtion continuous. A function is continuous, or it is not.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia saying a function “can be made continuous” is imprecise at best, and clearly was confusing to OP. It is more common to say that there exist a continuous extension $\tilde{f}(x)$ that agrees with $f$ except at removable discontinuities.

Comment: @adfriedman That is a good point. I meant what you said.